# maven system properties on pom.xml for JUnit @Category not working

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml

I'm running my test automation using JUnit @Category.

I created interface file for each categories in my test cases.
medium.class, high.class , all.class

And both medium and high extend the All interface.

```
@Test
@Category(medium.class)
public void succeeded(){}

@Test
@Category(Medium.class)
public void failed(){}

@Category(High.class)
public class TestLoading extends BaseTest {}
```

and in my pom.xml

```
<properties>
 <category>tests.groups.Medium,tests.groups.High,tests.groups.All</category>
</properties>
```

then in plugin

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>${category}</groups>
```

When running  medium and high category there is no problem but when running the All category,

```
mvn clean test -Dcategory=All
```

the result is zero test run, What should be the problem? Thank you.

```
    [WARNING] Couldn't load group class 'All' in Surefire|Failsafe plugin. The group class is ignored!
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.264 s
```